# How to access a GCS Blob that contains an xml file in a bucket with the pandas.read_xml() function in python?

Tags: python, pandas, xml, dataframe, google-cloud-platform

I would like to access a blob file via the pandas.read_xml() function.
Like this:

```
pandas.read_xml(blob.open())
```

When printing the blob it looks like this:

```
<Blob: Bucket, filename.0.xml.gz, 1612169959288959>
```

the `blob.open()`function gives this:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper encoding='iso-8859-1'>
```

and I get the error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte`. When I change the code to: `blob.open(mode='rt', encoding='iso-8859-1')` I get ther error `lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1`.

Is there even a way to read in a xml file from a bucket on gcs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[read_xml()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html) can directly read GCS files. Just provide the GCS URI and it can transform it to a dataframe. See sample code below and testing:

Sample file stored in GCS:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns="http://example.com">
    <bathrooms>
        <n35237 type="number">1.0</n35237>
        <n32238 type="number">3.0</n32238>
        <n44699 type="number">nan</n44699>
    </bathrooms>
    <price>
        <n35237 type="number">7020000.0</n35237>
        <n32238 type="number">10000000.0</n32238>
        <n44699 type="number">4128000.0</n44699>
    </price>
    <property_id>
        <n35237 type="number">35237.0</n35237>
        <n32238 type="number">32238.0</n32238>
        <n44699 type="number">44699.0</n44699>
    </property_id>
</root>
```

Code:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_xml("gs://my-bucket/note.xml.gz",compression="gzip")

print(df)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Ricco D you are right! I think this should work, but apparently I still need to also send some key with the request as it says that I am unauthorized

Comment: @julez8000 you should export your service account credentials prior to running the code. You can export it in this manner. `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="<full_path_of_service_account_key>/key.json"` see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#passing_variable for more details.